# How to make my base terminal in VsCode like this

Tags: terminal, git-bash

[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDAmC.png)

This image is taken from Thapa Technical youtube channel and i want to make my terminal like this.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This terminal is zsh. So, you need to install zsh on your Windows machine and change setting in VSCode to use zsh terminal path. Look at this:

https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/updating-visual-studio-code-default-terminal-shell-from-bash-to-zsh-711c40d6f8dc

Comment: Thanks a lot but i have i single doubt..! is it safe to use or safe to install ..???

Comment: if it is for personal use, there is no issue with zsh at all! For company computer, you need to check the company policies or line manager etc

Comment: I want to use it with projects on my personal pc.! is it safe..??

Comment: yes, all people use it without any problem... vote for my answer :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your beautifull response & i want to install it but how could i do that please guide me